# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'store_id' and referenced column 'store_id' in foreign key constraint are incompatible

Tags: php, magento, magento2

[Table structure in phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3tV6.png)

create new table in my new module by InstallSchema facing this error when run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command  (magento 2.4)
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'store_id' and referenced column 'store_id' in foreign key constraint  are incompatible.

[image]

```
<?php

namespace Dealer\Sellout\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        /**
         * Create table 'sell-out-order'
        */

        $table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable(
            $setup->getTable('sell-out-order')
        )->addColumn(
            'id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'SellOut ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'company_user_id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Company User Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'customer_id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Customer Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'store_id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Store Id'
        )->addIndex(
            $setup->getIdxName('sell-out-order', ['customer_id']),
            ['customer_id']
        )->setComment(
            'Sell Outs'
        )->addForeignKey(
            $setup->getFkName('sell-out-order', 'store_id', 'store', 'store_id'),
            'store_id',
            $setup->getTable('store'),
            'store_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        )->addForeignKey(
            $setup->getFkName('sell-out-order', 'customer_id', 'customer_entity', 'customer_id'),
            'customer_id',
            $setup->getTable('customer_entity'),
            'customer_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        );
        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        /**
         * Create table 'sell-out-order-item'
        */

        $table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable(
            $setup->getTable('sell-out-order-item')
        )->addColumn(
            'id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'SellOut Order Item ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'sell-out-order_id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'SellOut Order Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'product_id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Product Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'name',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Product SKU'
        )->addColumn(
            'product_type',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Product SKU'
        )->addColumn(
            'sku',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Product SKU'
        )->addColumn(
            'qty',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Qty'
        )->addColumn(
            'store_id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Store Id'
        )->addIndex(
            $setup->getIdxName('sell-out-order-item', ['sku']),
            ['sku']
        )->setComment(
            'Sell Out Items'
        )->addForeignKey(
            $setup->getFkName('sell-out-order-item', 'store_id', 'store', 'store_id'),
            'store_id',
            $setup->getTable('store'),
            'store_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_NO_ACTION
        )->addForeignKey(
            $setup->getFkName('sell-out-order-item', 'sell-out-order_id', 'sell-out-order', 'sell-out-order_id'),
            'sell-out-order_id',
            $setup->getTable('sell-out-order'),
            'sell-out-order_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_NO_ACTION
        );
        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the table definition of store?

Comment: @kuh-chan photo attached

Comment: the structure tab would be more helpful. I assume that the definition of the column store_id in store is another than of the column store_id in your new table. 
Might be, that the one in store is a bigint, or unsigned, allows null; anything like this

Comment: I changed to 
            Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            Table::OPTION_UNSIGNED,
and i'm still facing the same error

Comment: @kuh-chan  structure tab uploaded

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're on Laravel 5.8 or above. This issue was at first never mentioned in Laravel update docs.

It's a column definition mismatch which throwing error on 'incompatible types'.
your 'store_id' column's type is 'smallint' which is incompatible to to the 'store_id' of the referred column(?). If you make sure both of same type, you can avoid this error. could you post the referencing table structure?

check carefully the types defined on each migration.

more here,

https://logic.edchen.org/how-to-resolve-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql/